# SSH to ldap client hangs when ldap server is not reachable on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ssh, ldap, sshd, openldap

I am using ubuntu 20.04 VM as ldap client and docker is my ldap server. When ldap server is not reachable ssh to ldap client vm gets hungs. Below are the auth logs
Dec 18 07:02:40 tpvm22 sshd[24790]: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as (null) - Can't contact LDAP server
Dec 18 07:02:40 tpvm22 sshd[24790]: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://10.53.2.180:389/: Can't contact LDAP server
Dec 18 07:02:40 tpvm22 sshd[24790]: nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable

cat /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd: files ldap

group: files ldap

shadow: files ldap

gshadow: files

hosts: files dns

networks: files

protocols: db files

services: db files

ethers: db files

rpc: db files

netgroup: nis

cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config

SyslogFacility AUTH

LogLevel DEBUG

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

UsePAM yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

PasswordAuthentication yes

MaxStartups 30:30:100

cat /etc/ldap.conf

ldap_version 3

rootbinddn cn=manager,dc=example,dc=net

pam_password md5

uri ldap://10.53.2.180:389/

base dc=example,dc=com